# Difference between the use of "I am able to .... " And "I have been able to..."

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I would like to understand Difference between the use of "I am able to .... " And "I have been able to..." while writing formal/official emails. Do I need to add perfect tense always while writing formal mails?

Comment: The difference I suppose is the difference between the present simple and the present perfect.

Comment: I would like to understand when to use the simple present and perfect if I am writing formal mails. Do I need to use perfect tense to add more depth?

Comment: I don't see the relevance of formal mails. In general you should use the tense that conveys the correct meaning. If you want to say you _are able_ to do something, you say that. If you want to say you _have been able_ to do something, you say that. In the second case I would expect you to actually have done it, in the first case I may expect you or ask you to actually do it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the relevance of formal mails. In general you should use the tense that conveys the correct meaning. If you want to say you *are able* to do something, you say that. If you want to say you *have been able* to do something, you say that. In the second case I would expect you to actually have done it, in the first case I may expect you or ask you to actually do it.

As answered by @oerkelens